# What is $Z( (X^2-Y^2, X^2+Y^2))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I do not know what to do with the following exercise:

> Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. Consider the ideal $I := (X^2-Y^2, X^2+Y^2)$ in $K[X,Y]$. What is $Z(I)$?

We defined $$Z(I) := \{x \in \mathbb{A}^2 \mid \forall P \in I : P(x) = 0\}.$$

The only thing I recognize is that $I = \bigl\{P \cdot (X^2-Y^2) + Q \cdot (X^2+Y^2) \mid P,Q \in K[X,Y]\bigr\}$.

However, I have no idea how I could compute the zeroes of $I$ from this. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Forget all the fancy algebraic geometry language: can you simultaneously solve the equations $X^2-Y^2$ and $X^2+Y^2$?

Comment: Not really. I understand that $X^2+Y^2 = (X-Y)(X+Y)$, so the zeros of $X^2+Y^2$ have to satisfy one of the conditions $X=-Y$ or $X=Y$. But I do not know what to do with $X^2+Y^2$. However, with $i := \sqrt{-1}$ we have $X^2+Y^2 = (X+iY)(X-iY)$, so $X=iY$ or $X=-iY$. But what is the intersection of these two sets?

Comment: If you plug in $X=Y$ (or $X=-Y$) to your other equation, what happens?

Comment: I just made an edit to my other comment.

Comment: Even with the edit, I'd really encourage you to try what I suggested: what happens if you plug in $X=Y$ or $X=-Y$ in to $X^2+Y^2=0$?

Comment: So indeed $Z(I) = {0}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131360/discussion-between-kreiser-and-3nondatur).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to KReiser's help I now have a solution:

We observe that finding $Z( (X^2-Y^2, X^2+Y^2))$ boils down to finding $Z(X^2-Y^2,X^2+Y^2)$. We note that $X^2-Y^2 = 0$ implies $X^2 = Y^2$ and using this on $X^2+Y^2 = 0$ yields

$$2X^2 = 0 \quad \text{ and } \quad 2Y^2 =0.$$

If we now assume that $\mathrm{char}(K) >2$ or $\mathrm{char}(K) = 0$, i.e. $2 \ne 0$ (as we always did in the lecture), this implies that $X = 0$ and $Y = 0$, so $Z( (X^2-Y^2, X^2+Y^2)) = \{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: Note that, working with the ideals, $(X^2-Y^2,X^2+Y^2)=(X^2,X^2+Y^2)=(X^2,Y^2)$. This can simplify things for you considerably, I ween.